# Statistics in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, statistics

Does Microsoft SQL Server 2008 create any statistics on its own? Or is it implemented in later versions? I know the way how can we create statistics, how query optimizer uses the statistics in query plan generation

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server creates index-level statistics (all versions. at least starting with 2000) on index creation (it also updates them when rebulding indexes)

SQL Server can also create column-level statistics (`AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS` should be set to `ON`) when it needs them to elaborate execution plan.

Here the things change: these statistics are also created in versions < 2012, but only for read write databases. Starting with 2012 these column-level statistics can be created in tempdb if the database is readonly, and prior to 2012 it could't, so you could see a yellow triangle "missing column statistics" in your execution plan when executing in read only database.
More on this here: [SQL SERVER – Statistics for Read-Only Database are in TempDB](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/11/29/sql-server-statistics-for-read-only-database-are-in-tempdb/)

Answer (score 0):

If Auto create statistics is true? -Yes, will create stats.

[image]

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2766/sql-server-auto-update-and-auto-create-statistics-options/

https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/auto-create-stats-disabled/